# Trouble connecting to azure file share

Tags: azure, powershell

### Function upload files to file share

```
Function UploadFiles  
{  
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Upload files to file share.."    
## Get the storage account context  
$ctx=(Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name 
$storageAccName).Context  
## Get the file share  
$fileShare=Get-AzStorageShare -Context $ctx -Name $fileShareName  
## Upload the file  
Set-AzStorageFileContent -Share $fileShare -Source $fileName -Path $folderPath -Force  
}
```

Here is the error I get

```
Set-AzStorageFileContent : Cannot bind parameter 'Share'. Cannot convert the 
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageFileShare" value of 
 type 
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.ResourceModel.AzureStorageFileShare" to type 
 "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.File.CloudFileShare".
  At line:22 char:37
 +     Set-AzStorageFileContent -Share $fileShare -Source $fileName -Pat ...
 +                                     ~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzStorageFileContent], 
 ParameterBindingException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
```

CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.File.Cmdlet.SetAzureStorageFileContent

Comment: `-Share`

Specifies a CloudFileShare object. This cmdlet uploads to a file in the file share this parameter specifies. To obtain a CloudFileShare object, use the Get-AzStorageShare cmdlet. This object contains the storage context. If you specify this parameter, do not specify the Context parameter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstoragefilecontent?view=azps-7.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the error is self-explanatory. `Get-AzStorageShare` returns an object of type [`AzureStorageFileShare`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.commands.common.storage.resourcemodel.azurestoragefileshare?view=az-ps-latest) whereas [`Set-AzStorageFileContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstoragefilecontent?view=azps-7.1.0) expects `-Share` parameter of type `CloudFileShare` (or `String`).

Two ways to solve this problem:

1. You can pass the share name (string) and context to `Set-AzStorageFileContent`. Something like:

```
Set-AzStorageFileContent -Share $fileShareName -Source $fileName -Path $folderPath -Context $ctx -Force
```

2. Use `CloudFileShare` property of `AzureStorageFileShare`. Something like:

```
Set-AzStorageFileContent -Share $fileShare.CloudFileShare -Source $fileName -Path $folderPath -Force
```